# How to select an element with an attribute that contains certain text?

Tags: javascript

I have this HTML code:

```
<li class="_33c randomtext3" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;pub_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}">
<li class="_33c randomtext5" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;year_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}">
<li class="_33c randomtext4" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;group_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}">
<li class="_33c randomtext7" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;pub_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}">
<li class="_33c randomtext5" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;pub_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}">
```

The order of the lines is varied, (using [2] doesn't work)

I want to delete the `<li>`  with a certain text (`data-gt="...group_comment..."`), `"group_comment"` is the certain text (the line 3, sometimes it is on another line).

I tried with `document.querySelectorAll('[data-gt]');` with a `NodeList(5)`, but how to find in that `NodeList` the certain text?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Use the attribute value selector and wildcard selector.

`document.querySelectorAll('li[data-gt*=group_comment]')`

See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/wildcard-selectors-and-in-css-for-classes/

```js
const matches = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gt*="group_comment"]')
matches.forEach( x => x.classList.add("hidden") )
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="_33c randomtext3" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;pub_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}"> pub_comment </li>
  <li class="_33c randomtext5" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;year_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}"> year_comment </li>
  <li class="_33c randomtext4" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;group_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}"> group_comment </li>
  <li class="_33c randomtext7" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;pub_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}">pub_comment</li>
  <li class="_33c randomtext5" data-gt="{&quot;alert_id&quot;:1576605904117859,&quot;notif_type&quot;:&quot;pub_comment&quot;,&quot;from_uids&quot;}">pub_comment</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I was working on same answer, but you beat me so I just stuck my snipplet in your answer. Delete it if you do not want it.

Answer (score 1):

You should use attribute selector combined with the contains modifier `*`

```
const commments = document.querySelectorAll('[data-gt*="group_comment"]')
```

You can see the different modifiers here: [Attribute Selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)